# Possible to add HTML input Value attribute in Razor for MVC 5?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to find a solution to have a value inside the input form at start, but I can't find any useful info and therefore I wonder if it's possible att all? When I right click one the webpage, I can see that there are a empty value, so perhaps it's is possible?

One solution would be to use plan HTML and not the `@Html.EditorFor` But I guess it's better to use Razor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Just set the value of `Test` before you pass the model to the view - the `EditorFor()` method sets the value attribute based on the model property (do not attempt to override it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand how you mean? Where should i put it? I have tested different options, but nothing works! I would like to add something like this: value="someValue"

Comment: In your get method, initialize a new instance of your model and set the value of `Test` and return it to the view - `var model = new MyModel { Test = "someValue" }; return View(model);` - Your `EditorFor()` method will generate a textbox with that value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, but I don't want a textbox like textarea, I just want to add a value to the html attribute VALUE, so the input field will have a default value when form loads. Have we misunderstood each other!? :)

Comment: That exactly what my last comment will do.It will generate an input (textbox, textarea or whatever based on the property type and data annotation). The `HtmlHelper` methods work by **binding** to your model property and if the value of your model property is `"xyz"` then `"xyz"` will be displayed in the view when it is first rendered,

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's working! Great! Thanks for the help!!